# Is Sentry compatible with Mongodb?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, sentry

Is Sentry (python/django) compatible with Mongodb?

If not, is there an easy solution to make it compatible?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sentry is built on a relational DB, and thus will require such for the foreseeable future. It's possible to implement most things in many NoSQL solutions, but the various types of indexes, and some of the (newer) advanced SQL would be a lot more work.

As an example, Sentry 2.0 includes a "Trending" option, which is calculated real-time, and would require writing a map/reduce query in something like MongoDB (whereas it just works everywhere else).

You can easily use the Raven client, and setup an additional Django site for the Sentry server. It's as easy as pip install django-sentry && sentry start

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. I setup django mongodb  (http://django-mongodb.org/reference/settings.html) and got sentry server running, but when I click on a message, it throws an exception because the message ID is not integers--i tried fixing this by altering sentry's urls to use \w+ instead of \d+. This helped. I then tried clicking the message again and it worked sort of, but there was another 500 coming up during POST requests to /sentry/jsapi/ -- the exception occurs when running this code:

```
method = conn.ops.date_trunc_sql('hour', 'date')
```

I don't want to mess with sentry any more.